# How to hide update button from shipping and billing address in checkout page in prestashop

Tags: smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

[image]

I am looking to hide "update" button and "Choose delivery address option" on checkout page in prestashop. which file i need to edit to do it?

Comment: You have 5 steps or rapid checkout enabled?

Comment: well it's one page checkout.

Comment: Ok, I'm updating anwser ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two way to hide those buttons.

**First: CSS**
Edit `addresses.css` placed in your template folder, I guess it's default template in your case, so the file is `prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/css/addresses.css`. Add this line of code:

```
/* 
 * We have to add #order (or #order-opc) selector to avoid to hide buttons 
 * in addresses page that is in my account area 
*/
/* This is for 5 step checkout */
#order .address li.address_update {
    display: none;
}
#order #id_address_delivery {
    display: none;
}

/* This is for one page checkout (opc) */
#order-opc .address li.address_update {
    display: none;
}
#order-opc #id_address_delivery {
    display: none;
}
```

**Second: Smarty/TPL**
Edit `order-address.tpl` of your template (if you have 5 step checkout) otherwise `order-opc.tpl`, in your case `prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/order-address.tpl` or `prestashop/themes/default-bootstrap/order-opc.tpl`

Search this select:

```
<select name="id_address_delivery" id="id_address_delivery" class="address_select form-control">
    {foreach from=$addresses key=k item=address}
        <option value="{$address.id_address|intval}"{if $address.id_address == $cart->id_address_delivery} selected="selected"{/if}>{$address.alias|escape:'html':'UTF-8'}</option>
    {/foreach}
</select>
```

And comment it ([how to comment in smarty](http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.basic.syntax.tpl#language.syntax.comments))

In bottom of the file comment this two lines of code:

```
{*{capture}<a class="button button-small btn btn-default" href="{$smarty.capture.addressUrlAdd}" title="{l s='Update' js=1}"><span>{l s='Update' js=1}<i class="icon-chevron-right right"></i></span></a>{/capture}*}
{*{addJsDefL name=liUpdate}{$smarty.capture.default|@addcslashes:'\''}{/addJsDefL}*}
```

I guess there is a third way, with JS, but I think it's useless.
Cheers ;)

Comment: no need of #order-opc in css and then worked for me. thanks man!

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking to hide the update address button when delivery and invoice address are equal and show it when they are different. Is there a fix for this please? Thanks

I tried adding in `ordre-address.tpl` the following:

```
{* ADDED IF TO REMOVE EDIT BUTTONS IF ONLY 1 ADDRESS *}
{if $cart->id_address_invoice == $cart->id_address_delivery}
{capture}<a class="button button-small btn btn-default" style="display:none;" href="{$smarty.capture.addressUrlAdd}" title="{l s='Edit Address' js=1}"><span>{l s='Edit Address' js=1}<i class="fa fa-chevron-right right"></i></span></a>{/capture} 
{else}
{capture}<a class="button button-small btn btn-default" href="{$smarty.capture.addressUrlAdd}" title="{l s='Edit Address' js=1}"><span>{l s='Edit Address' js=1}<i class="fa fa-chevron-right right"></i></span></a>{/capture}
{/if}
{* END ADDED IF *}
```

This hides, both buttons but on changing check box state page need refresh to show button state. I tried a Javascript refresh on entire page reload, but this removes checkbox state

Is there a fix for this in JQuery?

Answer (score -1):

Look for order-address.tpl in your theme folder.

Good luck.

Comment: No i have seen already in this file but i couldn't do what i need.